# Нужно ли ввести отдельную причину «вопрос закрыт, потому что не раскрывает причастность автора (д/з)»?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Предлагаю ввести отдельную причину закрытия вопроса «вопрос закрыт, потому что не раскрывает причастность автора (д/з)», потому что подобная формулировка используется очень часто и было бы удобнее каждый раз не писать пресловутое «д/з», а просто выбрать соответствующий пункт в меню.

Пожалуйста, сообщите свое мнение (либо с помощью голоса «за», либо с помощью ответа).

Comment: Опыт [соседнего русскоязычного сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/213987), возможно пригодится для вдохновения.